Find $x_0$ such that the sequence $ 2^n (x_n - \sqrt{3})$ is convergent

Let the sequence $(x_n)_{n > 0}$ be defined such that $$x_0 > 0 \ \ \text{and } \ x_{n+1} = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + x_n^2}}{x_n}$$
Knowing that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \sqrt{3}$ find $\ x_0 \ $ such that the sequence $$a_n = 2^n (x_n - \sqrt{3})$$ is convergent.

My idea is to use Stolz-Cesaro. Denoting $E(x) = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + x^2}}{x}$, we see that $E(\tan(x)) = \frac{1}{\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}$, so there exists a unique $\alpha \in (0, \pi/2)$ such that $x_0 = \frac{1}{\tan(\alpha)}$.
By induction, we get that $$x_n = (\tan(\frac{\alpha}{2^n}))^{(-1)^{n+1}}$$
I think that $x_0$ should be $\sqrt{3}$ for $a_n = 2^n (x_n - \sqrt{3})$ to be convergent, and this might work with Stolz-Cesaro, but I'm not sure how to prove it. Any help is appreciated.

Are you sure that $ E(\tan(x) ) = \tan (x/2)$? I get $\tan x + 2 \cot x$. $\quad$ Also, the subsequent claim of $x_0 = 1/ \tan \alpha \Rightarrow x_n = (\tan (\alpha/2^n) ^ {(-1)^{n+1} }$ doesn't make sense to me.

@CalvinLin I corrected it.

Solve: $$x_{n}=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+x_{n-1}^2}}{x_{n-1}} \implies x_{n-1}=\frac{2,x_{n}}{x_{n}^2-1}$$ Set: $$x_{n}=\sqrt{3} \implies x_{n-1}=\sqrt{3} \implies x_{0}=\sqrt{3}$$

@HazemOrabi You have a problem of division by $0$

If you set $f(x) = \frac{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}$, you have $x_{n+1} =f(x_n)$, thus if you find a fixed point, it is enough.
Now things are well made since $f(\sqrt{3}) = \frac{1+\sqrt{1+3}}{\sqrt{3}} = \frac{3}{\sqrt{3}} = \sqrt 3$, thus if you set $x_0 = \sqrt{3}$ you have $x_n = \sqrt{3}$. You can prove it by recursion:

$x_0 = \sqrt{3}$
if $x_n = \sqrt{3}$, $x_{n+1} = f(x_n) = f(\sqrt{3}) = \sqrt{3}$

Now with this, you have $a_n =2^n(x_n-\sqrt{3}) = 2^n(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{3}) = 0$, which is convergeant.
In any case, if you wish to find all the $x_0$ satisfying this, we must study more closely the properties of $f$, first its fixed points.
$$\begin{align*}
f(x) = x & \iff x^2 = 1 + \sqrt{1+x^2} \iff y = 1 + \sqrt{1+y} , \, y = x^2\\
&\iff y^2-2y+1 = 1+y , \, y = x^2\\
&\iff y(y-3)= 0, y = x^2\\
&\iff y=3, \, y = x^2
\end{align*}$$
This means the only fixed point is $\sqrt{3}$, so if the sequence $x_n$ converges, it must be to $\sqrt{3}$, but what's important is the convergence speed.
Let us study $f'$, we have for $x > 0$
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x} + \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x^2}}$$
so
$$f'(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{2}{x^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}} = -\frac{1}{x^2} \left( 1 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \right) < 0$$
and you can check that $f'' >0$ thus $f$ is strictly convex, this means we need to determine the point where $f'(x) = -1$.
You can find that there is only one solution for some $a < \sqrt{3}$, so using Banach fixed point theorem you should know that for every $x_0$ in $]a,\infty[$, $x_n$ converges geometrically to $\sqrt{3}$ but this is not very important because we are gonna show that if $x_0 \neq \sqrt{3}$, $a_n$ diverges.
A first constatation is that for $a_n$ to converge, $x_n$ must converge to $\sqrt{3}$, so suppose $x_0 \neq \sqrt{3}$ and $x_n \to \sqrt{3}$, then since $f'$ is continuous and $f'(\sqrt{3}) = -\frac23$, there exists $a,b$ such that $\sqrt{3} \in ]a,b[$ and $f'([a,b]) \subset [- \frac 45, -\frac 35]$.
Furthermore here exists $k$ such that $n \ge k \implies x_n \in ]a,b[ $, this means that for $n \ge k$
$$\begin{align*}
|x_{n+1}-\sqrt{3}| &= |f(x_n) - f(\sqrt{3})| \\
&= \left |\int_{\sqrt{3}}^{x_n} f'(t) dt \right| \\
&\geq |x_n-\sqrt{3}| \cdot \min_{[a,b]} |f'| \\
&\ge \frac{3}{5} |x_n-\sqrt{3}| 
\end{align*}$$
By a simple recursion, you obtain
$$|x_{n+k}- \sqrt 3| \ge \frac{3^n}{5^n} |x_k - \sqrt{3}|$$
This means that
$$|a_{n+k}| = 2^n |x_{n+k}- \sqrt 3|\ge \frac{6^n}{5^n} |x_k - \sqrt{3}| \to \infty$$
Thus if $x_0 \neq \sqrt 3, \, a_n \to \infty$ and if $x_0 = \sqrt{3}, \, a_n = 0$.
In summary:
$$\left(a_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb N} \, \text{converges} \, \iff x_0 = \sqrt{3}.$$

Could you please elaborate cause I don't really understand the fixed point stuff and  if it's enough. And if n tends to infinity don't we encounter the case infinity*0?

It's not infinity * 0 its just a constant $0$ sequence

Take $x_0 = \sqrt{3}$. Then you can show by induction that $x_n = \sqrt{3}$, using the definition of the sequence. Because of this, we know that for this value of $x_0$, $a_n = 0$ for each $n$. Hence, $a_n$ is obviously convergent, since it is constant.

How can you get that inequality without using integrals because I haven’t studied them yet?

You can’t but if you just need the $x_0$ just stick to the first part, it answers your question so please accept it. For the second part I suggest you study a bit more maths before trying to understand otherwise it will seem overly complicated to you @math.enthusiast9

Not an answer, it's a remark on the behavior of $x_n$.
As mentioned before, since $x_0>0$, the only possible limit is $\ell = \sqrt{3}$. It was also mentioned that an easy choice would be to take $x_0=\sqrt{3}$, which would lead to a constant (hence, convergent) sequence.
More generally, if you are able to identify an interval where the conditions of the fixed point theorem hold, you can take any initial approximation in that interval. Taking $I = [\sqrt{3},+\infty[$, and observing that $g(x)=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}$ is invariant and contractive in $I$, the fixed point theorem guarantees that $g$ has a single fixed point in $I$ and that the sequence $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$ converges to that fixed point , regardless of the initial approximation $x_0 \in I$.
Noting that if $x_0 \in ]0,\sqrt{3}[$ we have $g(x_0) \in I$, we can actually show that the sequence converges for any $x_0>0$.
Using similar arguments, you can show that any $x_0<0$ will lead to a sequence converging to $-\sqrt{3}$.
The answer to the actual question, provided by @julio_es_sui_glace, comes from establishing a lower bound on $|x_n-\sqrt{3}|$ that shows tha divergence of $a_n$ when $x_0 \ne \sqrt{3}$.
